# Migration path from SO to AskUbuntu?

Tags: feature-request, migration

As I've read on the SO blog, only useful migration paths will be 'unlocked'. It seems to me that SO => AskUbuntu is a viable path. Take for example this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939847/ubuntu-lucid-maverick-high-iowait

Of course SU is also more suitable then SO, but it seems second best compared to AskUbuntu (AU?).

Some more examples, some already migrated to SU:

- [build recent numpy on recent ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933923/build-recent-numpy-on-recent-ubuntu)
- [Installing Ruby on Ubuntu 10.10 using RVM, problem with gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928965/installing-ruby-on-ubuntu-10-10-using-rvm-problem-with-gem)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910941/how-to-get-back-ubuntu-gnome-again-closed
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906373/ubuntu-installation-closed
- [ssh doesn't auto start up in ubuntu 10.04 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903982/ssh-doesnt-auto-start-up-in-ubuntu-10-04-64bit)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886977/cant-start-ubuntu-10-04-what-steps-to-take-closed

Just browse the 'ubuntu' tag, I guess around 20% there belongs to AU.

Comment: I agree, that post should be on ask ubuntu

Comment: In order to get AskUbuntu on to the migration path I think you will need post a few more examples.

Comment: Although one could take the -> SU -> AU route...

Comment: Then maybe we should [only do this for questions tagged `ubuntu`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags)?

Comment: By now I get more and more disturbed that I can't flag questions on SU or SO to migrate to AU. How many examples are needed to establish this migration path?