# Move questions other sites like crossvalidated.com (stats.stackexchange.com)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration, off-topic

On the R-tag we're often confronted with statistical questions that belong on crossvalidated.com (formerly stats.stackexchange.com). However, when it is voted to close being off-topic, there is no way we can specify that it belongs there. Is there a possibility this site (and probably other related sites) are added? Maybe just keep an open slot where you can actually add the URL of the site? Or a drop-down menu specifying "other"?

I also wonder if it's possible to move questions from SO to a daughter site, and if so, who has the power. It would keep things more clean, and especially, it would allow those people to get the right public, i.e. statisticians instead of programmers.

EDIT : Even if there is no link, it would at least be nice of +10k users on the r-tag could move those questions to crossvalidated.com. Most of those +10k users are also on crossvalidated.com, as the topics are closely related.

eg :

[Kolmogorov-Smirnov or a Chi-Square test for a distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332327/kolmogorov-smirnov-or-a-chi-square-test-for-a-distribution)

[solving St Peterburg Paradox in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310784/solving-st-peterburg-paradox-in-r)

[Log Likelihood using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301228/log-likelihood-using-r)

[implementation of the Gower distance function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298870/r-implementation-of-the-gower-distance-function)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242604/about-auto-arima-question

[randomized SVD singular values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224031/randomized-svd-singular-values) (has been asked on crossvalidated.com as well)

[Partial data sets in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216298/partial-data-sets-in-r-closed)

[Getting Probability Density of Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214504/r-getting-probability-density-of-data)

[two-sided censored model in R (similar to Zeligs Tobit)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186190/two-sided-censored-model-in-r-similar-to-zeligs-tobit)

[optimizing a function to find global and local peaks with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398160/optimizing-a-function-to-find-global-and-local-peaks-with-r)

[Regression with Heteroskedasticity Corrected Standard Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385436/regression-with-heteroskedasticity-corrected-standard-errors)

[Why does this code not optimize for all three points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368080/why-does-this-code-not-optimize-for-all-three-points)

[Calculate Newey-West standard errors without an an lm object in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403433/calculate-newy-west-standard-errors-without-an-an-lm-object-in-r)

[Heteroscedasticity robust standard errors with the PLM package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433490/heteroscadicity-robust-standard-errors-with-the-plm-package)

From half november to date.

Comment: Related question : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags

Comment: Also related question: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/505/what-migration-paths-should-we-allow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add some links to questions that should be/have been migrated. If there's enough evidence a link may well be added, but Jeff has [stated](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1595/add-a-migration-path-to-pro-web-masters-from-super-user/1704#1704)

> **We don't ever want to show more than 5 here, because it gets overwhelming.**

(His bold).

There are current four migration paths (here, Server Fault, Super User and Web Masters) so there is a "slot" available. However, a more useful migration path is probably to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) but that site's not out of beta yet.

Comment: @ChrisF: examples of the last three weeks added. Seems enough to me. It would also be a great help if +10k users could at least move those questions. Quite some of the +10k on the r-tag are also on crossvalidated.com

Comment: @Joris - that's a good list. It might be enough, but it's not up to me ;)

Comment: @ChrisF I had always assumed that slot would go to Programmers, since it has more migration potential than any other site.  It's a shame it's limited to five because there are a couple of sites like Cross Validated that do have very good reasons to migrate.

Comment: @C. Ross - that's a good point and I'd completely forgotten that. Programmers is probably a more useful target. We have the same problem on Super User, there are probably 6 or 7 valid migration targets but only 5 slots (all filled).

Comment: @ChrisF: Is there an overview of unlocked migration paths somewhere? As my rep is too low to close questions, I don't think I can see the possibilities per site.

Comment: @Jan - no I don't think there is. You only get to see what they are when you vote to close. I feel a question coming on.

Answer (score 9):

I once proposed to [add sites to the migration list based on the question tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags). This way, the Statistical Analysis Stack Exchange would only show up as a migration destination if the question is tagged `R` for example. This would give "smaller" sites a chance to get migrated answers, without clogging up the list.

Comment: I love that idea. Thx for the link, I added it as a related question

Comment: @Joris: Thanks, and if you find other similar requests from "small" sites, please link them to this proposal so it gets some traction.