# Can we have a page where users can see (and possibly vote on) the migration paths available

Tags: feature-request, migration

**UPDATE**

This is now not needed due to the moderator "migrate anywhere" option. So just flag the question and there's no waiting.

---

Prompted by a comment on [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71339/off-topic-belongs-to-addition-of-other-sites-like-crossvalidated-com/71340#71340) to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71339/59303) about a migration path from SO to Cross Validated I had the following thought.

I think it would be useful for all (for a given value of all) users to be able to see which migration paths are currently open for a site.

**NOTE: The following was a subsidiary idea**

Further to this it might also be useful for 3K+ users to be able to vote on which sites occupy the available slots. Jeff has stated [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1595/add-a-migration-path-to-pro-web-masters-from-super-user/1704#1704) that he doesn't want more than 5 migration targets to be shown and that the 1st is always the site's meta. So the votes would be on which sites occupied the remaining four.

This could be a dynamic thing with the current top four sites being shown (what ever they are) or a periodic thing where the sites change only when one reaches a certain threshold of votes.

There should be a restriction of 4 votes per person (one for each slot).

Comment: This is now not necessary given that moderators can now migrate to any site in the network.

Comment: I think it's still relevant, because flagging is not the same as voting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this kinda makes sense, I'm wondering how much of this can be handled in rough format inside of a Meta thread. This is more applicable to the sites that have per-site-meta, as they have these threads already... but maybe that just means we should create our own thread here.

This method doesn't have any kind of automation or mechanical maintenance. We'll just have to, say, put in big letters on the main post what the current paths are. This method is immediately available, has no restrictions on how to structure it or who can contribute, allows very clean discussion (well, it's messy, but it's no messier than what we already get), and it doesn't require developing yet another voting schema that needs to be balanced as to what is most appropriate.

Most sites don't actually have that many contenders for where things will really need to build migration paths for. So I feel that developing a whole system for this is not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Users voting is not useful for this; what is useful is tracking what kinds of questions *actually* get closed as off-topic, and picking the top 4 migration destinations based on that close data.

Therefore, every vote to close is a *de facto* vote for which migration destination paths get unlocked.

Comment: Fair enough - the voting was only an afterthought.