# Which site should I use for my question? And where do I find this info? - Stack Exchange's Site Directory

Tags: feature-request, support, site-recommendation

When creating a new question I want to post it on the most relevant site. But what site is that? E.g. I know from experience that stackoverflow.com is programming related, but otherwise I look at the list of sites in the bottom of all the pages, and open each potential site in a new tab and look at each of them.

After looking around a bit, I've since found [Stack Exchange's Site Directory](https://stackexchange.com/sites). I'd like to suggest that a link to [Stack Exchange's Site Directory](https://stackexchange.com/sites) be placed in the bottom of all the pages along with the list of sites, so it is easier to determine the correct venue for a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the Stack Exchange site I'm looking for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249845/how-do-i-find-the-stack-exchange-site-im-looking-for)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It's a specific feature request.

Answer (score 1):

When you writes a new question, it is automatically done a search to see if other similar questions have already been posted. This is to encourage the poster to check first if an answer is already out there before posting a new question.

Could it be a similar functionality to pick up typical wordings that are more relevant on other SE pages? Maybe linked to tags at least. I.E. if the poster adds a tag called `photo` or `exposure`, he would get a list of other sites that has use a lot of similar tags that he can click on to re-direct his question to. For his example the [Photography](http://photo.stackexchange.com) site would come up in the list.

Another thing that might also be useful, is for a poster to be able to redirect his question to another site at a later point, as a result of comments from others. This functionality would be useful to keep good answers that has already been answered. Now those are lost if you have to delete it in the original site, and create a new one where it belongs.

Comment: The tag sniffing sounds interesting. As for your last paragraph, I believe there's a whole tag here dedicated to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration

Comment: I just found a separate post that proposes this tag thing: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags