# How can I choose the best Stack Exchange site for my question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which site should I use for my question? And where do I find this info? - Stack Exchange's Site Directory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72100/which-site-should-i-use-for-my-question-and-where-do-i-find-this-info-stack-e)

Is there a tool somewhere which will help me decide which site is best for my question?

I believe this could be done through the tags, but sometimes I have a question. Also, some sites have greater communities (in terms of size), and even if the people are generally less qualified, it means that my question is more likely to be seen.

Answer (score 5):

Start here: https://stackexchange.com/sites

If you can't narrow it down to a single site, you're welcome to ask a question here on Meta and we can give you a specific recommendation.

You can also try "asking the network" your question, by using the search box on http://stackexchange.com (top right corner). This box is special in that it searches *all* network sites. This may help narrow things down.

Comment: I feel that this won't scale :) I hope there are thousands of SE sites sooner or later, and choosing the right one will probably be a little bit cumbersome :(

Comment: @Julien: Agreed. I updated my answer with an additional suggestion.

Comment: @JulienGenestoux, yes, I think it became so: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/12007/how-to-choose-a-community

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you should ask on [whereshouldIpost.stackexchange.com](http://whereshouldIpost.stackexchange.com):

> *WhereShouldIPost?* is the Q&A for beginner question askers looking for the correct StackExchange site where to post their question - check out the FAQ!

Comment: I don't get it.  I click on your link and it says not found.  Or is this a joke I'm missing?

Comment: @User: it was a joke. It would be hilarious if the SE network went so meta to have a site for users to ask question about where to post their questions. `:P`