# Searching for Stack Exchange site by some word in name of site?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, search

How, within any one of the Stack Exchange sites, or from the Stack Exchange site itself, do I search and find the link to a Stack Exchange site by *title*, versus by content of the questions inside those sites? Specifically, the end result of the search should not return links to particular questions in that site, but only to the links to the "top" of the site such as [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

This is not the same as [choosing the best Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72727/how-can-i-choose-the-best-stackexchange-site-for-my-question). That is a different (albeit quite useful) use case from this one.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#name and read the list? Seriously, specialised requirement or what?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you click on the Stack Exchange "hamburger" at the right hand end of the top bar on any site, then at the bottom of its pulldown you can click on **Find a Stack Exchange community**, and type in a search string like "android" to find Android Enthusiasts, and click on it:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could go to the [list of all Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and use your browser's search function (typically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

That way, you can search the site names as well as the tag lines.

Alternatively, you can use the [filter interface](https://stackexchange.com/filters); the site input field filters the site list as you type.

Comment: The filter interface is not on the "list of all Stack Exchange sites" link you posted.  So, how are users supposed to find that feature without doing what I did just now by posting here? Edit: that filters by question and not by title. And using ctrl-f assumes that the list of stack exchange sites will be included all in one page, but that is not scalable when the number of sites grows beyond what they can present on one page.

Comment: @bgoodr Dunno. Technically there is no option to search for sites by name (just the [Stack Exchange search](http://stackexchange.com/search)), I just told you two workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not a perfect fit but you can search https://stackexchange.com/search which return *both* sites of the Stack Exchange network and particular questions on them.

For example if you [search for "tex"](https://stackexchange.com/search) the first hit is [the Stack Exchange site for TeX and related typesetting systems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) and the following hits are particular questions on that site.

Comment: Right. Fair enough. But that does not specifically narrow it down to the title of the sites themselves, but only returns the questions.  Subtract the "and particular questions on them" part of your answer and that would be the answer I'm looking for.  Perhaps the empty set is the answer I must live with.