# How do I find the Stack Exchange site I'm looking for?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, faq-proposed

Say I have a question and I'm not sure what Stack Exchange site to ask it on. Is there a place to ask a question and get it routed to the correct Stack Exchange site?

Comment: This should be a [tag:faq].

Comment: Sure But first `Say I have a question`, Please tell us your question.

Comment: @Computerone: In order to give him advice *on which site to post* we need the actual question, but in this case we don't since it is about the step before that.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes exactly that is what I am asking for.

Answer (score 9):

First, you need to do some homework. So, having your question in mind, you could think of a few keywords to search for. You can [search for your question](https://stackexchange.com/search) in the network broad search page on StackExchange.com.

If not found, check the site list if there are some sites that could fit. Then read the [`help center > Asking`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page to see if your question is on-topic there.

If you are still not happy or in doubt, and need some advice, you can ask your question here, as Martijn told you in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249846/245360).

Answer (score 8):

Asking about where to post your question is on-topic here.

Tell us as much detail about your question as you can and tag your post with [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) and we'll tell you a) *if* the question would be suitable for the Stack Exchange model and b) on what sites it could be on topic.

Comment: In general: Isn't that too much? Asking each time the same question twice, once here, to get it routed to the proper site, then there again?

Comment: @DavidBalažic: I didn't say you had to post the question itself.

Comment: @ .. strange it does not autocomplete.. Yes, but you'll have to tell the basics of the question, not the whole but still smilar. The point is there are still two questions, a "meta" question and the actual question. I [asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253896/176236) more or less the same thing. A search that would take some keywords and spit out the most fitting sites would be great: faster than asking on meta and it does not require work from other members (to answer the meta question).

Comment: @DavidBalažic: the whole point of asking here is because you don't *know* where to post your question. If you knew where to go, why ask here?

Comment: @DavidBalažic: I doubt that it is easy to automate this task by typing in a few keywords. `android` can mean any of Stack Overflow, Android.SE, or SciFi or Movies, to give you a very simple example.

Comment: @DavidBalažic: and my name doesn't auto-complete because I am the author of this answer and there are no other people commenting here but you and me. There is no ambiguity about whom would be notified in that case.

Comment: 1.) I guess this i a matter of opinion. Some would say, the user should research himself instead of asking "simple" questions, other recommend just go and ask".
2.) Of course, a single keyword like _android_ would match a lot, one would have to enter more to get a useful answer, like on any other search engine.

Comment: @DavidBalažic: Meta is no different from other sites, we do expect you to share your effort when asking a question about where to ask a question.