# How to select the best/correct site for a question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

For some issues it is not clear to which SE site they belong. Either they "match" more than one, or none. Or you don't know all existing sites and miss the correct one.

Is there some recommended way to solve this problem?

I just try to do a quick search on SE for some keyword and the see what I get, but the search returns questions and answers instead of sites. Should just go with the one appearing most on the first page of results? Is there a way to get a list of sites sorted by relevance (by number of matching posts or other metric)?

Or simply search thru the descriptions of the sites at https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list ? (probably too terse)

Comment: You could always post a site-recommendation question here if you have found multiple sites your question could fit.

Comment: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)