# Looking for a project similar to UN CartoTile

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where would be the best place to ask this question?

> I am looking for **a website** that I briefly viewed in the recent
> past but cannot find in my browser search history anywhere.
>
> The site provides **map data** (geojson I think) that is **similar in
> style to the UN CartoTile** style of map found here:
> https://www.un.org/geospatial/mapsgeo/webservices.  That is, the site
> has data that will render a simplified, blocky style administrative
> regions on a map.
>
> **If** I am recalling correctly it was a fairly recent project, open source, and was from a pretty well known organization. On the home
> page there was a graphic showing the blocky administrative regions of
> Europe I think.  I believe with a purplish color.
>
> It definitely is not the UN site but here is a screen capture from the
> link above for reference.
>
> [image]

More research on posting: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249846/1238100

Answer (score 4):

The [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request) site also has a meta post about [what a good data-request question should look like](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look). The [help site](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) includes "where to find any kind of open data" in its list of on topic questions.

Comment: That's a nice way of redefining an identification question :)

Answer (score 2):

If it provides map data, it's a Geographic Information System, for which we have a [dedicated site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Most of the questions there are about *using* such systems, not identifying them. They're not in [the list of sites that accept identification questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357530/295232) but that doesn't mean they're off-topic, it could be that they are just rare. I found [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/194085/85703) which was well-received, so I'd give it a try.

Comment: Identification questions rarely fare well at GIS but can be asked in its GIS Chat Room.

Comment: I guess you mean [this chat room: GIS](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis)