# Where should I ask a question about NFS Most Wanted (2005)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I had a problem with the PC game *[Need for Speed: Most Wanted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_for_Speed:_Most_Wanted_(2005_video_game))* (2005). In which StackExchange community should I ask it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which site should I use for my question? And where do I find this info? - Stack Exchange's Site Directory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72100/which-site-should-i-use-for-my-question-and-where-do-i-find-this-info-stack)

Comment: R u serious this is not duplicate

Comment: Sure, the question `Where should I ask about NFS?` has not been asked, but the question `Where should I ask about a video game or game dev tool?` has been asked a lot. Browsing the [Site Directory](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) should easily answer all these kind of questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can ask any gaming-related questions over on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).**

For this question, you would want to use the tags [nfs-most-wanted-2005](/questions/tagged/nfs-most-wanted-2005),
 [technical-issues](/questions/tagged/technical-issues), and [pc](/questions/tagged/pc).

Make sure to spend time writing a detailed explanation of your issue and the troubleshooting steps you have tried before posting.