# Dynamically List Off-Topic Stacks Based on Tags

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrate shortlist based on tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags)

When voting to close a question as off-topic, the same list of other StackExchange sites to refer the question to is used for all questions in a given StackExchange site. As the number of StackExchange sites has increased, the chances that a question should be referred to an unlisted StackExchange site has increased. It would be useful if, based on a question's tags, the list of referable stacks could contain sites that are likely to be applicable to that question.

An obvious example would be linking [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) to various database-related tags on StackOverflow. A significant number of off-topic questions with those tags end up directed to [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), so it seems like it would be convenient to have that site listed in the close voting. On the other hand, questions that don't have a database-related tag will almost never be referred to [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), so it doesn't make sense to add it globally.