# Intelligently display the sites displayed when closing question as 'off topic'

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, off-topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrate shortlist based on tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags)

Currently sites for migration displayed when closing questions as 'off topic' is limited. I know that I can flag the question for moderator attention in case the site to migrate is not available in the list. But can't the sites being displayed be decided based on the tags present in the question? I know that this will not be a complete solution but I feel it is better than displaying a static set of sites.

Comment: Can you give us an example of a question that you feel would benefit from your feature?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425112/how-to-install-linaro-optimized-ics-on-a-galaxy-s2-s3

Comment: And what do you think the migration options should be, based on that question's tags?

Comment: I think it can go to: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Naveen: Also, **don't migrate crap**. That question isn't too good. The site would not benefit from the migration.

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles: Thats just an example.

Comment: Then choose better examples.

Comment: Thanks to this meta post, that question will quickly be closed as NARQ.

Comment: @Naveen: The fact that you, a 30k user, feels that it would be something that ought to be migrated, clearly shows why community migration should be restricted.

Comment: Ok, then, it takes aproximately 3.5 seconds to flag for moderation attention and write "this should go to Android Enthusiasts", why not just do that? (Don't do it for your example question, though, unless of course you don't mind a declined flag)

Comment: **Counter proposal: Take away the migration option completely, it's clearly not working.**

Comment: @YannisRizos, I would consider that to be a truly intelligent display of options.

Comment: @YannisRizos: YES PLZ PLZ!!!! Add more mods if you worry about load, but the current system seems to be causing more problems than not. Either that, or make the paths only available to those with X rep on the destination site (dunno how well that would work, though)

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles All that has been proposed before, including an awesome feature to have a migration queue on the target site, where migrations would only go through if voted on by high rep members of the site. But unfortunately this isn't a tech problem, but a people problem, we took away the option to migrate to Programmers, it was all great for a couple of weeks, and now OPs just cross post their crap on ProgSE. We can build every awesome feature, but as long as it's so easy to circumvent, it'll just fail horribly.

Answer (score 4):

No, migration is a sensitive issue. You need to be sure if the post is on-topic on the other site. We already had a big issue with off-topic questions being shunted off to Programmers, and finally the migration path was removed. Even mods have to ask the destination-site mods about migrations at times.

IMO, community migration should be pretty controlled. You can't trust the community to know what's on-topic for the other site too much--the current migration paths are those which are commonly used and which have boundaries known to most user.

Also, **don't migrate crap**. The example you gave was, well, crap. If you think that it ought to be migrated (thus showing that you don't know that rule), I bet others do, too. What's wrong with flagging and letting a mod handle it?