# Display the wordpress.stackexchange.com as option to migrate questions tagged with WordPress?

Tags: discussion, migration

We have quite a few questions related to WordPress and a [StackExchange Network](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) that is specialized for it, why not allowing the https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ to be displayed for closing those questions for migration?

They have a better acceptance and answer rate over there not to mention that probably most of the questions are duplicates as in they exist on both sites(SO and WP.SE) from people's recommendation for them to try their question there instead so it would be convenient to eliminate both at once.

Comment: This might arguably be a better duplicate: [migrate shortlist based on tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags)