# Context sensitive "it doesn't belong here" options?

Tags: feature-request, migration

I've noticed that questions will come up that belong on another site within the stack exchange network, however the "it doesn't belong here" option only shows popular sites.

Is it possible to have a context sensitive flag box that reads the questions tags and provide the appropriate options to migrate the question?

For instance, question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217867/caught-exception-when-trying-to-configure-a-nicemenu-or-a-superfish

was flagged `drupal-7`,`drupal-modules` and `drupal-theming`, yet the option to migrate to the drupal SE site is not present:

[image]

Having context sensitive migration would allow the drupal site to appear in the selections.

I think this would be better than using the "needs moderator attention -> other" option, or flagging in another inappropriate way.

Comment: Related: [Migrate shortlist based on tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68022)

Comment: I feel like I'm talking to myself.

Comment: @AlEverett Thanks - I was unable to find a similar question when I looked originally.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just flag it under the 'Other' category and explain that it would be better on the Drupal.SE site.

Comment: That what I've done, however I feel this adds extra work for the mods to review the comments left.

Comment: @RobertH I agree with that, however, how many times would this likely to occur?

Comment: @Damien I've run into this sort of issue tons of times, and there've been enough duplicate questions of this sort that Robert H and myself clearly aren't alone

Comment: @StephenTG then the feature request is definitely needed (I wasn't sure).

Comment: Honestly though, in my eyes the biggest thing that's missing is a general off topic option (or a "This isn't about programming" one), since most of the proposals related to migration were shut down because people migrated garbage.