# Add migration option to Android Enthusiasts

Tags: feature-request, migration

Would it be possible to add a new migration option for closing off-topic questions and migrate them to [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)?

There's a number of questions that appear every day on SO with [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag that are not about programming but would be suitable for Android Enthusiasts website. I currently try to put an "other" reason for closing as off-topic but we might as well use the existing migration mechanism.

Comment: Yes! I have to comment with "This question should not be posted on SO. Instead try posting on Android Enthusiasts."

Comment: I'm skeptical...what number of questions do you see that should go to Enthusiasts?  Most of the questions I've seen from the android tag are on-topic for SO.

Comment: Quite similar percentage to off-topic question for sql-server tag and there's an option to migrate for them to dba SE. I guess the resistance to this idea is more the fact that Android is newer and not so established technology.

Comment: @szymon No, the limitation is that only five options can be displayed in the migration list. The only way Android Enthusiasts will make it on there is if it becomes one of the top five where questions here need to be migrated. There's no "just add it to the list" option.

Comment: @animuson Didn't know that. Would it be possible to make the top 5 based on tags in the question? Or is it too complex?

Comment: @Szymon [Migrate shortlist based on tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags)

Comment: @animuson Yes. Ok, so the right question has already been asked and my question was based on misunderstanding about how the migration feature works...

Comment: Keep in mind that users who aren't active members of the target site probably shouldn't be voting for migration anyways. That limits the usefulness of a long list further.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the comments I received into account and being more experienced on SO (and SE in general), I don't see my request as reasonable any more.

I can now see that having too long a list of migration sites woult only create more confusion and won't add much value to the closing process. The number of quesions that could be migrated isn't that high in general (even if the number can seem high to a user working in a particular tag only). In addition, offering this option might result in incorrect close voting, giving more work to mods.

I'll leave that question and this answer here for future reference.